# What is the difference between .class and .dex files?

Tags: java, android, jvm, dalvik

Of course, `.dex` files are for the Dalvik VM of Android and `.class` files are for the JVM. But I wonder if they have similar layouts (Constant Pool, Fields, Methods, Attributes, ...)? The bytecode is different, but are there Dalvik specific opcode equivalents to the ones from the JVM?

Comment: Never got into this, but this is a first step: http://www.slideshare.net/Bhavsidd/diff-of-class-and-dex-file (and this: http://www.dalvikvm.com/)

Comment: Look on this article, [Difference between .class and .dex file.](http://www.risesoftware.com/pg/blog/Bhavya/read/889/difference-between-class-and-dex-file)

Comment: @BinyaminSharet second link is parked now and doesn't contain any useful info

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Whereas a Java jar file has many class files, each APK file has only a single
classes.dex file, as shown below. According to Google, the APK format
differs from the class-file format for performance and security reasons.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There's a [Dex File Format](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format) and the [Class File Format specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-4.html) from the respective company.

These 2 files are completely different.

Comment: +1 The disassembler ddexer provides addtional information http://dedexer.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Links seem to  be broken

Comment: Fixed broken links.

Answer (score -1):

The Dalvik Executable format is the code, the VM executes. Dalvik VM can not execute Java bytecode, it must be compiled to dex, because it uses an alternate instruction set.

Read the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29).

Comment: The OP is aware of that already. Please read the first sentence of the question.