# Difference between bytecode in .class file and that of .dex file

Tags: java, android

I wanted to know what are the differences between - the bytecode in the .class files which are obtained after compilation of .java files and the byte code in the .dex file. Are they of different format? if yes, which format

Comment: http://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dalvik-bytecode.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Android applications are usually written in Java language and are executed in the Dalvik Virtual Machine (DVM), which is different from the classical Java Virtual Machine (JVM).
2. The DVM is developed by Google and optimized for the characteristics of mobile operating systems (especially for the Android platform).
3. The bytecode running in Dalvik is transferred from traditional JVM bytecode to the dex-format by translating Java .class files with the conversion tool dx. Contrary to the DVM, JVM is using pure Java class files.
4. JVM bytecode is composed of one or more .class files (each of these contains one Java class). During run time, JVM will dynamically load the bytecode for each class from the corresponding .class file. While Dalvik bytecode is only composed of one .dex file, containing all the classes of the application.
5. After the Java compiler has created JVM bytecode, the Dalvik dx compiler deletes all .class files and recompiles them to Dalvik bytecode. Afterwards dx merges them into one .dex file.

[source is here](http://forensics.spreitzenbarth.de/2012/08/27/comparison-of-dalvik-and-java-bytecode/)

Comment: Number 1 is not 100% true, since from Kitkat, optionally, and later Lollipop, definitely, DVM was replaced by the ART runtime environment.

Answer (score 11):

A JVM `.class` contains JVM bytecode. You can read the specification of JVM bytecode as part of [the *JVM Specification*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/), specifically, [Chapter 6: *The Java Virtual Machine Instruction Set*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html).

A `.dex` file contains [*Dalvik bytecode*](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dalvik-bytecode.html). Dalvik was the original VM used by Android. It has now been replaced by the Android Runtime. The original version of Dalvik was a pure interpreter, later a compiler was added. ART used to be a pure compiler, it compiled your code *once* ahead-of-time when it was *installed* (not *every time* when it is *run* as a JIT compiler does). As of today in 2020, ART is capable of interpreting, AOT-compiling and JIT-compiling.

The major differences between JVM bytecode and Dalvik bytecode are:

- the JVM is stack-based, Dalvik is register-based
- JVM bytecode was originally designed for interpretation, although most JVMs nowadays actually have compilers, whereas Dalvik bytecode was originally designed for compilation, although in the first versions it actually was interpreted

Answer (score 7):

You can find good info about the build process [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html).

[image]

Quoting,

- > All of your Java code, including the R.java and .aidl files, are
  >   compiled by the Java compiler and .class files are output.
- > The dex
  >   tool converts the .class files to Dalvik byte code. Any 3rd party
  >   libraries and .class files that you have included in your module build
  >   are also converted into .dex files so that they can be packaged into
  >   the final .apk file.

Sources from @Andreas comment provide technical insight for the [Dalvik bytecode](http://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dalvik-bytecode.html), which clearly is not Java bytecode.

Answer (score 1):

Dalvik doc: http://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/

Java doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/

These 2 docs are completely different. Read all your doubts will be cleared.

See this ans: [What is the difference between .class and .dex files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210173/what-is-the-difference-between-class-and-dex-files)

Note: Whereas a Java jar file has many class files, each APK file has only a single classes.dex file. According to Google, the APK format differs from the class-file format for performance and security reasons.